# template type as struct data member in SWIG

Tags: php, c++, templates, swig, language-binding

I am writing a PHP wrapper for a C++ library using SWIG, but I am having trouble using a structure with an instance of a template type as a data member.

Suppose I have the following header file:

```
template <typename>
struct myvector
{
};

struct S
{
    myvector<int> v;
};

myvector<int> foo();
S bar();
```

and interface file:

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.hpp"
%}

%include "test.hpp"
%template(IntVec) myvector<int>;
```

When I try to use a function that directly returns an `myvector`, it works fine:

```
$v1 = test::foo();
```

However, when I try to use a function that returns an `S` object, and try to access its data member which is of type `myvector`:

```
$s = test::bar();
$v2 = $s->v;
```

I get the following error at runtime:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'myvectorT_int_t' not found in test.php on line 145
```

I am probably missing something from my interface file, but I don't know what. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is myvector belong to some namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can make out this is a SWIG bug. Someone else has [already reported it](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=101645&aid=3428833&group_id=1645) in fact. Fortunately there's a simple, reliable workaround via PHP's [`class_alias`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php):

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%pragma(php) code="
# This code is inserted as a workaround for template bugs with SWIG
class_alias('IntVec', 'myvectorT_int_t');
"

%include "test.h"
%template(IntVec) myvector<int>;
```

The pragma here inserts the code to setup the alias at the start of the generated PHP file.

(There's another possible work around too - rather than using public member variables access via getter/setter functions works as expected)

The [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=101645&aid=3428833&group_id=1645) also mentions another possible workaround although I'm not keen on that since it requires using a rather ugly name for the template type.

---

### Justification for bug assumption

The code for `__get` includes:

```
$c=substr(get_resource_type($r), (strpos(get_resource_type($r), '__') ? strpos(get_resource_type($r), '__') + 2 : 3));
                        return new $c($r);
```

When you get here `$c` is set to `myvectorT_int_t` which would be correct except for the `%template` directive.

When we add a `myvector<int> get()` function to `S` the generated code results in:

```
 $c=substr(get_resource_type($r), (strpos(get_resource_type($r), '__') ? strpos(get_resource_type($r), '__') + 2 : 3));
 if (!class_exists($c)) {
     return new IntVec($r);
 }
 return new $c($r);
```

which crucially includes the generic code that would be correct without the `%template` **and** as special check to see if it's actually an `IntVec`.

There's also a comment in the `Source/Modules/php.cxx`:

```
// FIXME: Currently we always use call_user_func for __get, so we can
// check and wrap the result.  This is needless if all the properties
// are primitive types.  Also this doesn't handle all the cases which
// a method returning an object does.
```

Finally the code generated by the same interface file for Java is correct.

Comment: Your workaround works - thanks! Are you a SWIG developer by any chance? ;)

Comment: @HighCommander4 - no connection to SWIG other than I use it a lot and I like the hard questions that nobody else seems to answer on SO. I'm not familiar enough with the internals to patch the problem properly.

Comment: I see. The reason I asked is that I'm a bit disappointed with SWIG's apparent level of maintenance and support, compared to other open-source projects - bugs in basic features like this being open for months, questions on the swig-user mailing list going unanswered, and so on. It makes me wonder whether SWIG is suitable for use in a production environment. What do you think, as someone who uses SWIG a lot? Perhaps it's just the PHP module that's being neglected?

Comment: @high my perception is that swig is well maintained and cared for generally but that the PHP backend is much less polished than the Python or Java ones I normally use.

Comment: I've been using your suggested workaround and it seems to be pretty reliable. Bounty awarded, and thanks again! By the way, if you enjoy tackling SWIG-related questions, here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577075/iterating-over-stdmap-in-php-with-swig

Comment: I take back what I said about PHP being less cared for - it's been fixed with what looks like a pretty comprehensive overhaul quite quickly.